# Retrieving phone preferences

Tags: android

is there any way to retrieve phone info such as language so that i can use that to auto adjust the program based on the phone language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably read about localization for Android. It's probably as simple as including a text file that has all of your strings and the conversion strings in it. From there when your application is deployed it reads in these strings. You shouldn't want to manage this by yourself.

[Android Development - Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Comment: Thank you, going to check it out :)